# Allow only 1 (child) JFrame on the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a main JFrame. There is a button inside the frame. When I click the button, it opens the child frame.

But I only want only 1 child frame is opend at any time, (instead whenever i click the button again , it give me the second child frame, and so on...).

So, I added actionListener to the button, to make it disable when the child frame is openning, and add windowListener to the child frame, so that When i click the close button on the top-right corner, it make the button (on the main frame) able.

Here is my code :

```
 import java.awt.Button;
 import java.awt.EventQueue;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
 import javax.swing.JButton;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class Form1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 JButton btn1=new JButton("help");

public Form1() {
    super("Form 1");
    this.add(btn1);        
    setSize(200, 200);
    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==btn1){
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        final Form2 x= new Form2();
        x.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        x.dispose();
        btn1.setEnabled(true);


    }    

    });
    }        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
             new Form1();

        }
});    

}
}  

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Form2 extends JFrame {
JLabel lbl1=new JLabel("đang mở form 2 - trợ giúp");    
public Form2() {
    super();
    add(lbl1);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(200, 200);


}



}
```

So, my question is : Is there other way that I could let only one child frame opened (it means that when that child frame is opening, clicking the button in the main frame do nothing unless the that child frame is closed)?

Comment: BTW - *"đang mở form 2 - trợ giúp"* What language is that?  What does it mean in English?

Comment: It's Vietnamese, literally it means "Form2 is being opened - Help" :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Google translate's best guess was Filipino, Polish or Yiddish.  Not surprisingly, none of them worked well for that text.  It pays to restrict code samples to SO to English only.  That way, people can take clues from the title (or variable name, text content etc.) to make the best suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a fine way, but yes, there are other ways too. Your class could keep a reference to the child `JFrame`  as a member variable. The button could check if that member is `null` or disposed, and if so, create a new one; but otherwise it could just bring the existing child to the front.

Comment: When the use-case screams 'modal dialog', this answer amounts to being 'the right answer to the wrong question'.

Comment: Why Andrew, we must stop meeting like this :)  You may be absolutely right, but it really depends what sort of child it is.  It could be a palette sort of thing -- you only want one instance of the "Tools" palette in your paint program, for example, but it's definitely not modal.

Comment: For a Tools palette I would leave it embedded in the GUI in a `JToolBar`.  The user can drag it from the GUI if they like.  For non-modal components that are singletons, keep a reference to the original instances and simply `setVisible(true)` &/or `toFront()`  on subsequent occasions.  I just don't see the point of p1ssing about trying to make a frame behave like something else, and maintain the basic principle of **One frame per application.**  So far I've yet to see a good justification for multiple frames.  ( And if you say 'GIMP', I might start swearing ;)

Comment: Yes, good points all: one should use the proper tool for the proper job.

Comment: BTW - +1 for the `null` check/lazy instantiation.

Answer (score 7):

Use a modal dialog instead.  See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

> A Dialog can be *modal*. When a modal Dialog is visible, it **blocks user input to all other windows in the program**. `JOptionPane` creates `JDialogs` that are modal. To create a non-modal Dialog, you must use the `JDialog` class directly.

Answer (score 2):

Build the Form2 ahead of time and use setVisible(true) to show it and and setVisible(false) to hide it. Here as an example:

```
if(e.getSource()==btn1){ 
    btn1.setVisible(false); // not really needed if you disable form1 on btn1 press
    form2.setVisible(true);  // show form2
    form1.setVisible(false); // hide form1
}
```

Comment: This is a variant of Ernest's prior answer, but Ernest's is better as it includes a null check with lazy creation of the window if null.

Comment: 2 people thought this was a good answer?!?  -1 to help bring some sanity back.  `form2.setEnable(true);`  As an aside, there is no `setEnable` method.  But editing the answer to that effect will not reverse my down-vote.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Wow - how'd I miss that...Thanks I changed it to setVisible().  I need a vacation.

Comment: @ChuckFricano  I change my mind about not removing the down-vote.  We both need a vacation.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - No worries - I'm actually more interested in learning/teaching than in points - but thanks.

Comment: I was one of the so called upvoter on this one, I never looked at the code snippet, I just looked at the theory part, which stated `setVisible(true/false)`, and no doubt it's a good alternative and good practice to initialize your variables, rather then heading towards `NullPointerException` :-) . Moreover the comments in the code snippet, clearly stated the purpose.